# NiFi: Consume from Kafka Topic without moving offset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, offset

I was wondering if in Apache Nifi exists a processor that peeks the "current" (i.e. where the offset is right now) event from an Apache Kafka topic but without moving the offset to the next event in Kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no processor that currently does this. The consume processors write the data to NiFi's repositories and commit that operation, then commit the offsets to Kafka, to guarantee NiFi has the data before committing the offsets.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have a question about the guarantee: if NiFi consume an event from a Kafka topic, then commit also the offset to Kafka, if it happens a fault, and then the consumed event dosen't get processed by the next processors in the pipeline, what does it happen when i make NiFi restart? I have lost that event?

Comment: No the data is persisted in NiFi and will still be there, that is why we commit to NiFI's repositories before committing the offset